# Finding latitude and longitude using Android.Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.ios, gps

I am trying to develop a store locator app in Android.Xamarin. My first step is to find my location's latitude and longitude.

But my emulator/device screen shows nothing.

I have my `uses-permissions` set to `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

This is my code:-

```
Location _currentLocation;
    LocationManager _locationManager;
    TextView _locationText;
    TextView _addressText;
    string _locationProvider;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        _addressText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address_text);
        _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.location_text);
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.get_address_button).Click += AddressButton_OnClick;

        InitializeLocationManager();
    }

    void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
        {
            Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
        };
        IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

        if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
        {
            _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
        }
        else
        {
            _locationProvider = String.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();
        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause ()
    {
        base.OnPause ();            
        _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
    }


    async void AddressButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            _addressText.Text = "Can't determine the current address.";
            return;
        }

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        IList<Address> addressList = await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

        Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
        if (address != null)
        {
            StringBuilder deviceAddress = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
            {
                deviceAddress.Append(address.GetAddressLine(i))
                    .AppendLine(",");
            }
            _addressText.Text = deviceAddress.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            _addressText.Text = "Unable to determine the address.";
        }
    }
    #region ILocationListener implementation
    public void OnLocationChanged (Location location)
    {
        _currentLocation = location;
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            _locationText.Text = "Unable to determine your location.";
        }
        else
        {
            _locationText.Text = String.Format("{0},{1}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled (string provider)
    {       
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled (string provider)
    {       
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged (string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
    #endregion
```

I get the output as the following:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should use google play service lib for that..

Comment: @Segi can you please provide a link for a tutorial or reference. This is the first time Iam using Xamarin for Map apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are executing this code in emulator then keep this in mind that Emulator doesn't display GPS Information. And when you are trying in above code in real device, make sure, your GPS is turn on and you should be below open sky or near Window.

Comment: Thanx for your response. I did test the code on a real device near an open window. But the same results. Also do you think the above code would work?

Comment: For first time It may take 2-5 minutes to fetch the GPS details.

Comment: @Vibgyor you were right.. Got the coordinates after testing it outside the building. thankx