# Latitude and Longitude using Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, location, xamarin.forms

I am working on a project where in I need to fetch users current location.
I have decided to make use of XamarinForms to build my project.

I have found many tutorials for obtaining latitude and longitude using Xamarin.Android like this one:
[Finding latitude and longitude using Android.Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946293/finding-latitude-and-longitude-using-android-xamarin)

But none using Xamarin Forms. 
Can anyone help me out in obtaining latitude and longitude using XamarinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms doesn't have a built in GPS service.  You have two general options to get this into your app

1. Use the Forms [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to inject Android GPS service into your app
2. Use [XF Labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs), which has a Forms friendly GPS service

Comment: There's also Geolocator plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Geolocator